# Website asks for "Authentication Required" on an MVC controller, but not others

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, iis-7, routes

I have an asp.net C# MVC website. It uses SimpleAuthentication and forms authentication. Everything works fine, requiring people to log in to go to pages. However, I have one controller called "ReportsController". Whenever you go to the URL's of the actions within this controller it always pops up with "Authentication Required" in the browser window.

It is only doing it for this controller and not any others. The URL will be "www.domain.com/reports". This URL works fine when I run from IIS and from my development server, but not on my live server. This is running IIS7.

I have checked my web.config and it is definately set to Forms authentication and not Windows.

Anyone have any ideas why any urls beginning with "/Reports" would not work. I am guessing it is something specific to the server, such as an IIS setting or web.config change, but I cannot figure out what this would be.

```
namespace ProjectName.Controllers
{
    public class ReportsController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            throw new SystemException("here");

            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Web.config:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
```

Comment: Does your reports controller have any custom attributes on the controller or actions that may be applying a filter to implement security?

Comment: I was using [Authorize] on the action, but I have tried commenting that out for the moment and not getting any joy.

Comment: I have added the code to the question so you can see. Nothing special about the controller or action.

Comment: Not sure, if Reports can be a reserved word for IIS? Did you try changing name of Reports controller like MainReports or ReportsOut with any prefix or postfix?

Comment: I had that thought too, but it runs fine on my machine and development server. All other controllers work fine.

Comment: I have managed to find a similar question. with "Reports" URL's. They were not able to find an answer either: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14741863/mvc-action-returns-401-error

Comment: From the question above I have tried disabling Sql Server Reporting Services on the servier and I now get a 503 Service unavailable error. So it appears that this is hijacking the URL. I now need to find out a workaround for this.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

So it turns out that Sql Server Reporting Services was running on the server. This was taking control of the "/Reports" URL on all websites on that server.

I am not using SQL Server Reports, so I went to "Reporting Services Configuration Manager" on the server and removed the IP address and port it was listening on. You can also change the URL it uses instead if you still need to use this.

Comment: It won't let me accept my own answer for two days for some reason, but this solved it.

Comment: Same problem here - I didn't know Reports was running elsewhere.  It's always somethin'

Comment: Really glad I found this! I was scratching my head for days about this one!

Comment: Thanks a lot. you save me. if possible, i want to transfer all of my points ;)